# How to redirect an error 404 to home page with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, http-status-code-404

Hello how do I redirect an error 404 to a home page with .htaccess?

Example:
**site.com** if write **site.com/some_site_notforund** instead of 404 redirects us to the main page

Example 2:
**sadistic.pl** if write **sadistic.pl/some_site_notfound** instead of 404 redirects us to current page

Comment: https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/how-can-i-redirect-a-404-page-not-found-to-the-index-of-my-site.82846/

Comment: And this is it? ErrorDocument 404 /index.html

Comment: Have you already set AllowOverride directive to httpd.conf to enable .htaccess?

Comment: yes, ok i have this code ErrorDocument 404 /  witout index.html and work

Comment: @Taizo ito How do you AllowOverride in ClearOS webserver?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try:

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

or whatever the homepage is

---

try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: this is not work for my server. I looking some simular redirect to sadistic.pl if you write http://www.sadistic.pl/testowymasrekadaksdaksdad/ url stil work and not rederict to sadistic.pl  sory for my english

Comment: @seweryns you'll need to use mod rewrite then, see edit above

Comment: In which part of the `.htaccess` these lines must be placed? Inside the `<IfModule mod_rewrite/c>`? Or outside?

Comment: Best approach is - `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php`

Comment: @Wolfack If index.php uses relative links, the links might be broken depending on the path the user was trying to go to.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this like

this will be .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

All the page not found pages will display *404.php* file.

In *404.php* file you can write:

```
<?php
    header('location:index.php');
?>
```

So all page not found pages will go to *404.php* page and it will redirect them to *index.php*

Answer (score 6):

Or save a reroute step and just put the following into your .htaccess file:

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

Comment: or  ErrorDocument   404   http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php  ( add the http :  //  infront pls ). It keeps being removed by SO

Comment: This approach will display the index.php relative to the directory of where their (broken) link is.  So unless the missing page linked to was in / (unlikely), all relative links in index.php will be broken, including links to css and js.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make a .htaccess file in your root directory.
2. Put this code into it and customize the RewriteRule.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ http://127.0.0.1/dir/index.php [L]
```

Works perfectly on my localhost.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for my site. I tried this code, it doesn't show 404 pages, but it shows the same URL but content of the homepage

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```