# React router V6 "catch-all" route not working in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router-dom

I have my routes all set up and the catch-all (404/not found) route works perfectly fine when in React's development mode. However, as soon as I build the application to production and host it from my server, locate to a route that is not anything else aside from one of the predefined routes OR localhost:3001/[not defined route], it loads a blank page.

For example:

- If I go to localhost:3001/**[notdefined]**, the 404 page will render
- If I go to localhost:3001/pricing/**[notdefined]**, a blank page renders

I have changed my code in multiple ways using other questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324649/react-router-not-working-after-building-the-app) but I have had no luck.

I have tried adding a `basename` prop to the `BrowserRouter` component and it doesn't work. I've tried making parent routes and giving each child of the parent route a catch-all route and still no luck. I have attempted it using `'/*'` instead of just `'*'` and that doesn't work either.

frontend/package.json:

```json
"name": "site-name",
"version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.88.7",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.15.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.7.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-ga4": "^2.1.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.3.0",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.5.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.18.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-waypoint": "^10.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.48.0",
    "three": "^0.158.0",
    "web-vitals": "^3.5.0"
  },
```

frontend/index.js:

```
<React.StrictMode>
   <BrowserRouter>
     <App />
   </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
```

frontend/App.js:

```
<div className={light ? 'light' : 'dark'}>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home {...props} />} />
    <Route path='pricing' element={<Pricing {...props} />} />
    <Route path='portfolio' element={<Portfolio {...props} />} />
    <Route path='tos' element={<Home {...props} tos={true} />} />
    <Route path='*' element={<Error404 {...props} />} />
  </Routes>
</div>
```

And I have an express server that handles all the requests and sends the `index.html` file when a request is made (app.js):

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || (process.env.npm_lifecycle_event === 'build' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')) {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend/build')));

  app.get('/*', (_, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html')));
}
```

In the above, I have the `(process.env.npm_lifecycle_event === 'build' && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')` there just to serve the files when I'm testing locally. I'm not sure if that's the correct way of doing it, however.

---

Anyway, with this code, I can run `npm start` on the backend folder which will run this script:

```json
"start": "concurrently \"cd frontend && npm run start\" \"nodemon app.js\""
```

- I can then go to localhost:3000/pricing/**[notdefined]** and it will load the `Error404` element.

But, if I cancel that process and build the react application with `npm run build` and following from that, I run `npm run build` on the backend which runs 'app.js', then:

- I go to localhost:3001/pricing/**[notdefined]**, the `Error404` element is not rendered and instead, all I see is a blank page with the following errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

site.webmanifest:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

l:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
```

I am really confused and I have absolutely no idea what to do.