# Hiding existance of directory and file structure with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to hide my website structure and redirect all possible requests to one file (index.php) with .htaccess.

Right now I use .htaccess to deny permission to read images and directories and redirect requests to index.php. If anybody requests forbidden dir/file, it shows E403. I want to redirect the request to index.php in that case, no E403.

So basically: I want to start processing every possible request (existing/non-existing page, .php file, image, other file, dir..., except css and js) in a single file (index.php), no matter what, so the user will see my index.php content every time (generated from many files on server side, depending on URI). My .htaccess can hide image content, but not the structure and PHP files. If anybody requests invalid URI, it's working (index.php shows error message), but if somebody requests for an existing PHP, it's executing it.

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "\.(log|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|ico|jfif|pdf|phtml)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(css|js)$ index.php [L]

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define specific error page in `php` or `html` format. and you can redirect your visitor to specific page

```
    ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
    ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.php
```

For example in `404.php` you can use these code :

```
header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
```

or if you wanna use `index.html`you can do this :

```
<html>
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
    </head>
</html>
```

or also can do something like this :

```
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
```

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897979/) is also helpful

and for your new comment you the answer is "Yes". you can process an extension as another extension, take look at this code :

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .mp3
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /load.mp3 /load.php
```

this code will add mime-type and will proccess `.mp3` files as `.php`
you also can use this code :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+).mp3$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025252/7903663) is useful too

Comment: Good idea with E404/E403, thanks. Any idea about running single PHP scripts from subfolders? My only idea is to rename them as something like "ScriptName.XXX", add rule to process XXX as PHP and deny access to XXX files (as I do with images).

Comment: This is a great answer all around, kudos to @GameO7er. Yet I'd add this obligatory thing: if possible, better move your file out of web root for maximum protection. Apache config can be broken (by upgrade, or typo in main http.conf, or whatever else reason), and your files will suddenly become available to the world.

Comment: @alx What do you mean? Move the whole web to some subfolder with impossible-to-guess name?

Comment: Move it outside of webroot, e.g. if webroot is `/var/www/html`, put sensitive files in `/var/www`. That's the best way to defend. But not always possible, I must admit.